# Getting data from MongoDB with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, each, mongoose, underscore.js

I am trying to put a number of documents from a MongoDB collection into an array, using `node.js`&`mongoose`. Logging the `userDoc` in the `_.each`-loop works fine, but not appending them to an array.

What am I doing wrong?
My best guess is that I have misunderstood something regarding node's asynchronous design, but I have no idea on what I should change.

**The code with comments:**

```
returnObject.list = [];

Users.find({}, function (err, user){

    _.each(user, function(userDoc){             
        console.log(userDoc); // Works
        returnObject.list.push(userDoc); // No errors, but no users appended
    });

});


console.log(returnObject); // No users here!

res.send(JSON.stringify(returnObject)); // Aint no users here either!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah this is a nice one, you're trying to do something in an synchronous style:

```
Users.find({}, function (err, user){
  // here you are iterating through the users
  // but you don't know when it will finish
});

// no users here because this gets called before any user
// is inserted into the array
console.log(returnObject);
```

Instead you should do something like this:

```
var callback = function (obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}

Users.find({}, function (err, user){
  var counter = user.length;

  _.each(user, function(userDoc) {
    if (counter) {
      returnObject.list.push(userDoc);          
      // we decrease the counter until 
      // it's 0 and the callback gets called
      counter--;
    } else {
      // since the counter is 0
      // this means all the users have been inserted into the array
      callback(returnObject);
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

do a `util.inspect(user)` to see what you have before the each loop.

Comment: Yep - the user data is there and shows when running that, so I am not running this on an empty collection